# Google Checkout and charge-amount-notification

Tags: c#, google-checkout, android-pay

I've got all the initial code working that handles the purchase for the user through Google Wallet and submits the actual charge to their credit card. Also in the setup I specified a post-back url for this where I capture the order details like the order number, price, item name, etc and I save them to my database.

But when I look in Google Wallet under 'orders' I see the order flagged in yellow with the description 'chargeable' (after awhile it will turn to green and be marked 'charged') so clearly there needs to be some checking to make sure the charge was made successfully before I treat it as such. The Google documentation says that I need to receive a **charge-amount-notification** back from them to confirm that the charge was successful. But I see no good examples for this or instructions on how to implement it. Do I need to poll their API for a success code or something? I really just need a good example in C# so I can see how this all ties together and how best to proceed.

thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify which API, it _seems_ you are referencing Google Checkout API (which is near deprecation date - Nov. 2013) re: `charge-amount-notification`

Comment: @EdSF -thanks for the reply...yes all the docs I found online refer to the Checkout api but the code i've written so far ties into Google Wallet (which as I understand it is the successor to Checkout). That's where I am lost...do I implement the Google Notifications API to get a status back on the order?

Comment: Just to make sure - Google Checkout will be [deprecated in 11/2013](https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/answer/3080449). AFAIK, the entire API will be deprecated (unless otherwise noted by Google). There really is no "replacement" per se because the other Payment APIs are markedly different.

Comment: [Instant Buy API](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/online/) and [Wallet for Digital Goods](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/) are the "Wallet APIs" (links are to respective documentation).